# How to enable multilingual toolkit for "WPF Application" .NET 7.0 type project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2022, multilingual-app-toolkit

In Visual Studio, there are two similar-looking project templates for WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) applications: "WPF Application" and "WPF App".

I am using "WPF Application" .NET Framework 7.0. With VisualStudio 2022 Version 17.4.5

I am trying to enable MAT 4.1 (Multilingual AppToolkit) but it gives error:

**Project 'xxx' was not enabled - it is not a supported project type.**

This is very strange and what can be done here ?

Things I have done so far.

1. Created a Resources.resx under properties folder.
2. Edited project file and inserted NeutralLanguage. Other tags where already existing.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After this i was expecting it would enable MAT, but it keep giving me message "it is not a supported project type."

Any Help/Guidance. Thanks

Comment: [Use the Multilingual App Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-mat) suggests to use 4.1 with VS 2022.

Comment: Hi Clemens, I just checked in Extensions Manager of VS and found green tick , which shows that Multilingual App Toolkit 4.1 (VS 2022+)  is already installed/upto date

Comment: @Neha same issue. Did you ever resolve it?